# UILabel underline text with high characters below baseline

Tags: ios, text, uilabel, nsattributedstring, underline

I'd like to make underlined text for a `UILabel`. For now, I'm using:

```
self.lbValue.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: value, attributes: 
    [NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue])
```

It does draw a single line under the text, that's alright. However, when the character is high (and fall below the base line), it crops the line and makes ugly blank space between the line, like this:

[image: high characters]

As you can see, there's a tiny dot below the characters. That's where my underline go. How do I make a solid line and overlaps the characters? Like this:

[image: Expected output]

I've tried other style (dash, dot, thick, solid...) none of them work as I expected.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved in other better way as well.I will show you an example-:

1) Add a label and, UIView below that label(Which will work as underline).

2) Provide appropriate constraints.

Check image Below-:

**Label Constraints-:**

[image]

**Underline View Constraints-:**

[image]

Now in controller class add `Outlets`. And, also add `width` **NSLayoutConstraint** for underline `UIView`.

As I suppose your label `width` can change dynamically we will give underline label(Width) an **intrinsicContentSize** . This will adjust underline label `width` based upon content in `UILabel`.

Controller Class-:

```
import UIKit

class UnderlineViewController: UIViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var myLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var underLineWidth: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var underline: UIView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // SET TEXT FOR LABEL
        myLabel.text = "What's next in Game Of Thrones"
        // MAKE UNDERLINE VIEW WIDTH INTTRINSIC
        underLineWidth.constant = myLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

**Output-:**

[image]

[image]

**Hope it helps you.**

Comment: lol it's a hack =]] I don't mind it, but I was expect some stuff related to text drawing. Thanks for your answer :) Also, how would you do it if it's a `UITextView` or `UIButton` or `UISegmentControl`? You can't, eh? :)

Comment: @Eddie yeah you can say that and it would not even work with multi line label , for that we need to use what you have in question.

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting you to add a label with height as 1 and width equal to the width of the label and pin it below the content label(set background colour of the label to your desired underline color).

This may not be a solution which you were expecting,  but it will solve the requirement. :)